# How to design the consumation of a REST API from SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, windows, rest

I'm using a desktop application that writes its data to SQL server. I don't have the source code of this application nor is there an API I could interact with but I do have access to the database.

Besides this desktop application, I'm working with other web based applications that offer a REST API for interaction.

Now, my goal is to act on specific changes I make in the desktop software and push these changes automatically to the web service. For example, if I create a new customer in my application, I want to have the same customer created in the web service.

The easiest way of doing this IMO is to just introduce a trigger in the SQL database and consume the API of the web service directly from T-SQL.

Researching this topic, I came across many comments saying using SQL Server for this is not recommended, too expensive etc. I fully understand where they are coming from, even though in my own case cost or performance really won't matter that much.

Still, I'm wondering, what would be the correct (or at least better) way of doing what I'm trying to do without considerably blowing up complexity?

Comment: Have a task queue (table in your database), fire your trigger, add a task to the queue, consume the queue from a service which polls the database. Too big a topic for one question.

Comment: _consume the API of the web service directly from T-SQL_ But you can't. TSQL has no functionality to do that at all. Do not confuse the use of the fragile, error-prone, and difficult to implement/diagnose OLE automation procedures with actual useful, built-in, well-tested functionality.

Comment: To take this a step further, you have a license to use an application - typically that means you cannot change the schema of the associated database (if you want to be supported). Adding a trigger is one of those changes. If you're not careful and lucky, you just might break your system.

Comment: @SMor I'm actually officially supporting this application so I'm not too worried about breaking something, I know the schema by heart :) But you're right, I was talking about OLE automation, of course, and I understand it's not a very good path, just not sure which alternatives exist.

Comment: @DaleK I guess it is a big topic but your comment still is appreciated. I assume you would work through the queue and have one field that would flag if the task was already processed or not, right? Would you store the JSON in the queue or would you build it from the service? Since SQL 2016 we have some nice capabilities in this respect.

Comment: @vic whatever suits your purpose - there are many considerations here, I suggest doing some research.

Comment: Not that SQL Database Mail is a great example, but dbmail is a queue example like DaleK suggested. Ultimately there's an external .NET Framework-based console executable that's responsible for dequeuing new mail messages from the database and transmitting them to the configured SMTP servers, finally updating the queue tables with the outcome.

Comment: So I guess reading about the SQL Server service broker is probably a good place to start? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/bb522893(v=sql.105)